# Are there any scale invariant activation functions that outputs probability distribution?

Tags: neural-networks, activation-functions, probability-distribution, softmax

Softmax activation function is used to convert any random vector into a probability distribution. So, it is generally used as an activation function in the last layer of deep neural networks that are intended for classification.

But, the `softmax()` does not satisfy the property of scale invariance i.e., the ratio of inputs and the ratio of outputs does not remain the same.

For example if we give the input `[1.4285, 0.3815]` to `softmax`, the function will give `[0.7402, 0.2598]` as output.We can calculate ratios `1.4285: 0.3815` and `0.7402: 0.2598` and find that they are not the same.

Are there any scale-invariant versions of softmax?

Comment: Could you explian why you need a scale-invariant function? Unmodified logits in a neural network can be, and often are negative. They cannot be simply scaled into a discrete probability distribution. However, if you are willing to accept other non-linearities to adjust this, then something may be possible. But it not clear whether what has driven your question, thus whether such a thing would be a good idea.

Comment: @NeilSlater The text book I am reading mentioned about this property explicitly. So, I think there might be some significance and hence asked it.

Comment: Can you give a reference to where it is mentiioned and in which content? As far as I know there is no function that could turn arbitrary logits into a discrete probability distribution without impacting their ratios. Non-linearity is required to deal with negative inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just divide the numbers by their sum? If your numbers could be negative, you can clamp them to a probability of zero by passing them through a RELU activation.

Comment: I am asking for reputed ones in application.

Comment: I don't think there is any other function which preserves the ratios of numbers `[0, a, b]` and scales them to sum to 1. You explicitly ask if there is such function, and I answered that yes there is and provided an example.